# Table Partitioning in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I've followed [this](http://www.mkyong.com/database/partition-table-in-postgresql-create-partition-part-1/) to partition my large table, for example what i've done is

```
create table g09_6(check(acyrid = 6)) INHERITS (gtab09);
create table g09_5(check(acyrid = 5)) INHERITS (gtab09);
ALTER TABLE g09_6 ADD CONSTRAINT g09_6_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tranid);
ALTER TABLE g09_5 ADD CONSTRAINT g09_5_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tranid);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX g09_5_tranid_idx ON g09_5 USING btree (tranid);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX g09_6_tranid_idx ON g09_6 USING btree (tranid);
insert into g09_6 select * from gtab09 where acyrid= 6
insert into g09_5 select * from gtab09 where acyrid= 5
```

Here `gtab09` is *parent table* and `g09_5` and `g09_6` are the *child tables*.And given below is my *trigger*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gtab09_func_insert_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.acyrid = 5 )THEN
        INSERT INTO g09_5 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSIF ( NEW.hashtime = 6 )THEN
        INSERT INTO g09_6 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error function!';
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_gtab09_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON gtab09
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE gtab09_func_insert_trigger();
```

- So, when i perform `select * from gtab09 where acyrid = 5` or `select * from gtab09 where acyrid = 6`, Taking time to execute (I think select taking place in child tables)
- Does `inherits` really splits the tables?

Comment: SELECT * FROM pg_tables; to see all tables and partitions and use EXPLAIN to see how the partitions are used in a query plan.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I found the solution from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION)i.e need to `SET constraint_exclusion = on;`

Comment: It should work without the explicit "on", I never used it but do use table partitioning a lot. If you don't turn constraint_exclusion off, partitioning should work.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I dint meant that my partitioning not working, the actual problem was the performance

Comment: Same thing, by default the query should only check the root table and all partitions that are needed by this query. Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE in both situations?